# How to compute for the estimated billing for the read and writes?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have 3 collections: `classifications`, `items`, and `orders`. Under items, I have a subcollection that stores the modifications made in the `items`.

Under `classification`, I have around 6 documents, each would have 3 fields. For the `items`, I have around let's 10 documents with 5 fields each. Under the `items`, is a subcollection that will store any modification made in `items`. For the `orders`, there could be a lot of documents under these.

How can I estimate the billing for the read and writes per month assuming that there's only 1 user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are charged based on the number of documents that you retrieve from Firestore irrespective of number of fields in them. In this case, if that user fetches all the documents from all these collections, then you'll you'll charged 3 + 10 + N reads where N is number of documents in orders collections.

If the users retrieved all these documents M times a day, then you'll be charged M × (3 + 10 + N) reads.

However you have offline persistence enabled, then you are not charged for documents that were fetched from local cache.

Comment: But I will only be charged if I reached the quota for 50k reads per day and 20k writes per day, right? And also what does the 10 here means in `3 + 10 + N` ?

Comment: @PennieCorhon yes so if you utilize the free 50K reads for the day, then you'll be charged for reads thereafter if you are on Blaze plan. If you are on free Spark plan then the SDK will just throw resource exhausted error

Comment: oh Thank you, what does the 3 and 10 mean here `3 + 10 + N`?

Comment: Number of documents in those 3 collections @PennieCorhon